# Can augmented reality be realized in a website?

Tags: augmented-reality

Nowadays, I wanna do some research of augmented reality technology.Especially, I would like to match a 2d image and a 3d model.And then, I will see the 3d model if scanning the 2d image. What's more, I know that there are a lot of SDKs(like metaio,and wikitude) and software can realize this in mobile app. However, what I want to do is realizing this in a website. I hope the people who use this don't need to download a particular mobile app, but just open a website and then scan a picture.
So, until now, I's like to know that,as the tile asked, can AR be realized in a website? If yes, how can I do it or is there any software like Metaio Creator to do this? If no, why?
Thank you for anyone who would like to answer my naive question.

Comment: Metaio has its own toolkit to use their API via Javascript [AREL](https://dev.metaio.com/arel/javascript-reference/) , unfortunately they have been acquired by apple lately

Comment: yup, as I have known , the metaio will not open any new user account.BTW, it seems that metaio does't support website AR.

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend you our completely webbased AR & VR tool holobuilder.com by bitstars.com?
It supports 360 degree photospheres that can be enhanced with custom 3D models and then directly be embedded into your website as iframe, it has native support for stereoscopic view mode and much more.

For your use case you could have a look at the lower part of this blog post where you find information and an embedded example presentation with photosphere imagery containing 3D elements:
http://heyholo.com/google-pushes-vr-great-for-tools-like-holobuilder/

If you want to start creating I recommend the beginners guide:
https://medium.com/@maxspeicher/the-definite-guide-to-holobuilder-3b62a54d303e

The cv feature tracking you requested can not yet be realized without any apps/browser. But what you can do is realizing perspectively correct displaying 3D elements into the camera image and move with sensors. Should be as performant as within the player app.

We hope that it can somehow help you in pushing your research and we would love to read your feedback. In case of any questions please do not hesitate to ask, here or on any other contact channel!

Comment: You can find more demo content on https://www.holobuilder.com/index.html#examples&ref=harrystov20150611

The mentioned separate standalone app for Android smartphones is available on Google play:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bitstars.holoplayer